# How do I create a BpfLoaderUpgradable update instruction using the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, deploy, multisig, sdk

I need to deploy a buffer to program_id using an app that utlizes a multisig contract. A prudent method to managing deployment is to upload to a buffer with a less trusted account and then use a trusted account or multisig program to upgrade the upgradable account to point to the new buffer.

I can do this using the cli with a ledger or keyfile wallet but in order to utilize the multisig with easy usability (eg. allowing a non technical to sign off) I really need to compose this transaction using the JS sdk and have it work in a dapp with a ledger connected browser wallet.

How do I construct the transaction data using the JSON RPC endpoint or JavaScript SDK for the following cli command to upgrade an upgradable program account:

```
solana program deploy --program-id XXXXXX --buffer YYYYYY
```

Ideally I would like to be pointed to a reference for how deployment transactions are created/put together.

I could not find anything on solana cookbook which is usually my guide for how to do stuff like this.

In the JS SDK there exists a load method on BpfLoader but that requires passing in the binary to load.

Any tips appreciated.